# it is not compiling. I am calling a function which is called by reference but there is an error which is can not convert double * to double

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void square(double);
void main()
{
  clrscr();
  double x;
  x=123.456;
  cout<<"\nThe value of i before calling square(), is :"<<x;
  cout<<endl;
  square(&x);
  cout<<"The value of i after calling square(), is :"<<x;
  cout<<endl;
  getche();
}
void square(double* x)
 {
  *x=*x**x;
 }
```

It is not working, why?

It is also not compiling.

I am calling a function which is `called by reference` but there is an **error**  which is

> can not convert double *  to double

Comment: Check your prototype of function square

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration and definition of `square` differ in their parameter types:

```
void square(double);
// ...
void square(double* x) { /* ... */ }
```

`square(&x)` tries to call `void square(double)` with a `double*` - that explains your error.

---

You're also using an ancient C++ compiler - `iostream.h` and `conio.h` are non-standard and outdated.

Your use of pointers is also non-idiomatic - `square` should take `double` by value or by `const` *lvalue reference*.